# Is BLE 5.0 impemented on Nougat version

Tags: applications, 7.0-nougat, java, 8.0-oreo, oxygenos

---

Is BLE 5.0 features accessible from Android Nougat phones ? if not how will be the connection of phones with Ble 4.0/ble 4.2 with BLE 5.0 before Android Upgradation ?

Comment: Bluetooth 5.0 wasn't a standard before Android 8.0, depending on the features you are looking for, there is always interoperability between 5.0 and 4.x BLE devices.

Comment: So once Android 8.0 is out , for accessing features of BLE 5.0 we have modify on the Android application side or  can we use the already existing callbacks for BLE